# Tools for Apache Cordova Builds Fail on TFS

Tags: android, cordova, tfsbuild, hybrid-mobile-app, visual-studio-cordova

I'm receiving errors building a Cordova app on TFS 2013.  Specifically, it always fails doing some sort of operation on a platform-specific screen.png file.  Other posts talk about the problem being related to the file being marked as read-only, but I've been unable to use any of the few solutions I found to get the build to work.  Any ideas?

```
...
                     Install complete for cordova-plugin-customurlscheme on android. (TaskId:12)
                     Executing "after_plugin_install"  hook for "cordova-plugin-customurlscheme" on android. (TaskId:12)
                     Searching PlatformJson files for differences between project vs. platform installed plugins (TaskId:12)
                     No differences found between project and android platform. Continuing... (TaskId:12)
                     Generating config.xml from defaults for platform "android" (TaskId:12)
                     Wrote out Android application name to "My App" (TaskId:12)
15:10:15.163     2>MDAVSCLI : error : EPERM, operation not permitted 'D:\Builds\Cordova\MyApp\src\MyApp\platforms\android\res\drawable-land-hdpi\screen.png' [D:\Builds\Cordova\MyApp\src\MyApp\MyApp.jsproj]
                   Done executing task "MdaVsCli" -- FAILED. (TaskId:12)
```

Comment: Is the build success from VS?

Comment: Yes, the build works just fine when we run it in VS (2015).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found a solution. I added a before_prepare hook to remove the read only flag from the files. I added the file hooks/before_prepare/undoReadOnly.bat with the contents below. Note that I had to edit these outside of Visual Studio and save them with ANSI encoding for TFS to be able to read them:

```
echo before_prepare hook - undoReadOnly
echo MSBuildProjectDirectory=%MSBuildProjectDirectory%
attrib -r %MSBuildProjectDirectory%\MyApp\platforms\*.* /S /D
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to check following things:

1. Make sure the path to "screen.png" isn't set to "Read-Only".
2. Make sure the account that the build service use has enough permission to access to the file. (Try to run build service with an administrator account)

If it still not work, try to add a step to check out the file before build. Same issue can be referred here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/81d5e57c-49bd-4487-a198-7930b48412b5/error-building-windows-x64-windows-x86-or-windows-anycpu

Comment: That file is read only, but I'm not sure how to change that.  It seems that Cordova itself sets that to read-only and I'm not sure how to hook into the TFS build process to stop that.  I checked the account and it does have R/W permissions to all folders and even that specific file.